# Copy directory to server after it is created

Tags: bash, unix, cp

I am working on a Mac computer using Bash commands and scripts via terminal.

I am running a process that creates ~3 million individual files and places them into consecutively numbered directories in groups of >5000 files. These directories are created as the process continues beginning with directory 0 and continuing until the process is terminated.

I am trying to create a command or script that automatically copies the created directories to a server after they are finished being filled with files. But i don't want to disturb the directory being actively written to for fear of terminating the ongoing process by rendering that directory unwritable.

My thought is to simply use `cp -u` but I am concerned that this could disrupt the process as it is actively writing to the highest # directory. I have struggled to find clarification on this point. I would test this... but each run of this process is time consuming and expensive and I don't want to mess it up.

Your suggestions are much appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: [rsync](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rsync)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @dawg for suggesting rsync.  Here is what i ended up with.

```
fswatch -o ./ | (while read; do rsync -r -t /Source/Directory /Destination/Directory; done)
```

Any suggestions or improvements are welcome!